# In a finite division Ring $a^{|D|} = a$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, finite-fields

I'm trying to show that $a^{|D|} = a$ for every $a\in D$, where $D$ is a finite division ring. My thoughts were to prove that the followign map
\begin{equation}
\phi : D \to D, \quad \phi(a) = a^{|D|}
\end{equation}
is bijective, but when I try to prove that $ker\phi = \{0  \}$ i see that i cannot have nilpotents elements on $D$, so I believe I'm not on the right track. So any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Look at the group of units, what is its cardinality?

Comment: I'm not sure $\phi$ will help you much; it is not obvious to me that $\phi$ is linear (in any reasonable sense). But have you tried regarding $D \setminus \left\{0\right\}$ as a finite multiplicative group?

Comment: @Melody wouldn't be $|D|-1$ ?

Comment: @darijgrinberg Ya, that was the other struggle, i couldn't prove lineearity on sum. I have not tried what u say, could u elaborate a bit more please

Comment: I hope you know that a finite division ring is necessarily commutative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Melody pointed out, the multiplicative group of the ring under multiplication has cardinality $\left|D\right|-1$, and thus by Lagrange's theorem, $a^{|D|-1}=1$. So $a^{|D|}= 1 \cdot a= a$.